# Ionic 2 : Load pages dynamically from external sources

Tags: angular, ionic2

**Problem: My app needs to dynamically load Pages supplied from external sources.**

The app will have a list of projects which will need to supply the whole html content and JS (preferably be able to use ionic components too with the HTML/JS supplied) and then render that into the ionic 2 app. The navigation and other architecture would be set within the app itself and doesn't need to be loaded from externally.

Is this possible with ionic 2?

Would really appreciate your help on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The current examples of Ionic2 all use webpack for building your app. This means that all code is bundled and served to the browser in one bundled file. I am looking fo a solution to your problem as well and there might be a possibility using webpack HMR or hot-module-replacement. this is used as a kind of live-reload during development, but i can imagine   the webpack-dev server running in production and transpile/build your modules on the server during runtime. https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/hot-module-replacement-with-webpack

Comment: Ronald, you are talking about Ionic Platform, right - not Ionic Framework per se?

Comment: See also https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/dynamic-template-from-url/48879/2 ...
Maybe one could modify 'template' to contain a function which determines what template to show (just to be able to show the different content)